# Altium: Change Net Label Size and Font at once!

Tags: schematics, altium

I have a complete schematic project in Altium Designer. I need to change Net labels text and font. Since I have a huge number of Net Labels, I am wondering if it possible select for instance 20 different Net Labels and change the size and font at once instead of change just one at a time!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can absolutely do this. Here's the process:

1. Select all of the net labels you want to change
2. Go to the bottom right of your screen and click the "SCH" tab
3. Open SCH Inspector
4. At the bottom of the window that appears, it will say how many objects are selected. Make sure this is correct. Within the SCH Inspector, you can change any attribute you want, and all selected objects will be changed to the new property.

If you want to change ALL of your net label properties, you can right-click on any net label and select "Find Similar Objects". In the window that appears just make sure that "Net Label" is set to "Same". Click "OK" and it will select all of the objects matching the criteria you set (in this case, it's just that the object  type is "Net Label"). Once the objects are selected, use the SCH Inspector the same way as described above.

Comment: Great, that's what i was looking for!!

Comment: That does not work on my Altium Designer 17. Up to a point, it selects everything, but does not globally change anything.

Comment: Make sure your scope is set correctly. It always worked for me